# Running job stops if start new running the same job - Spring Batch

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, spring-batch

### Issue

I am a bit confused, because when starting the execution of a Spring Batch job by HTTP request, if I receive another HTTP request to start the same job, but with different parameters while the job is executing, the job that is being executed stops unfinished and processing of the new job starts.

### Context

I've developed an API REST to load and process the content of Excel files. The web service exposes two endpoints, one to load, validate and store the content of Excel files in the database and the other to start the processing of the records stored in the database.

### How does it works

- POST /api/excel/upload
  This endpoint receives the Excel files. When a request is received, each file is assigned a unique identifier and its content is validated. If the content is correct, it inserts it into a temporary table waiting to be processed.
- GET /api/Excel/process?id=x
  This endpoint receives the identifiers of the files to be processed. When a request is received, a Spring Batch job is started to process the records in the temporary table.

### Some code

- Controller

```
@PostMapping(produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Page<ExcelLoad>> post(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile)
{
    return super.getResponse().returnPage(service.upload(multipartFile));
}

@GetMapping(value = "/process", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Void>> get(@RequestParam("id") Integer idCarga)
{
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Void>> response = new DeferredResult<>(1000L);
    response.onTimeout(() -> response.setResult(super.getResponse().returnVoid()));

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> service.startJob(idCarga));

    return response;
}
```

*I use DeferredResult to send a response to the client after receiving the request without waiting for the job to finish*

- Service

```
public void startJob(int idCarga)
{
    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("mainJob", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .addString("idCarga", String.valueOf(idCarga))
            .toJobParameters();

    try
    {
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
    catch (JobExecutionException e)
    {
        log.error("---ERROR: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

- Batch

```
@Bean
public Step mainStep(ReaderImpl reader, ProcessorImpl processor, WriterImpl writer)
{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<List<ExcelLoad>, Invoice>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ExceptionSkipPolicy())
            .listener(stepSkipListener)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job mainJob(Step mainStep)
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
                            .listener(mainJobExecutionListener)
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .start(mainStep)
                            .build();
}
```

Performing some tests I have observed the following behavior:

1. If I make a request to the endpoint /process to process each file at different times: in this case, all the records stored in the temporary table are processed:

   - Records processed file1: 3606 (expected 3606).
   - Records processed file2: 1776 (expected 1776).
     [image]
     [image]
2. If I make a request to the endpoint /process to first process file1, and before it finishes I make another request to process file2: in this case, not all the records stored in the temporary table are processed:

   - Records processed file1: 1080 (expected 3606)
   - Records processed file2: 1774 (expected 1776)
     [image]
     [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobLauncher` does not stop job executions, it only launches them. The default job launcher provided by Spring Batch is the `SimpleJobLauncher` which delegates job launching to a `TaskExecutor`. Now depending on the task executor implementation you use and how it is configured to launch concurrent tasks, you can see different behaviours. For example, when you launch a new job execution and a new task is submitted to the task executor, the task executor can decide to reject this submission if all workers are busy, or put it in a waiting queue, or stop another task and submit the new one. Those strategies depend on several parameters (`TaskExecutor` implementation, the type of the queue used behind the scene, the `RejectedExecutionHandler` implementation, etc) .

In your case, you seem to be using the following:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> service.startJob(idCarga));
```

So you need to check the behaviour of this pool with regard to how it handles new task submissions (I guess this is what is stopping your jobs, but you need to confirm that). That said, I don't see why you need this. If your requirement is the following:

> I use DeferredResult to send a response to the client after receiving the request without waiting for the job to finish

Then you can use an asynchronous task executor implementation (like the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) in your job launcher, see [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer).

Comment: I don't use a custom task executor and it isn't configured to launch concurrent task. I need to user ForkJoinPool to send a response to client, otherwise  the endpoint not response until job finish

Comment: I have tried with this and the behavior is the same: 

\@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher (JobRepository jobRepository, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher (); jobLauncher.setJobRepository (jobRepository); jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor (taskExecutor); return jobLauncher;
}

\@Bean 
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor () {
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor (); taskExecutor.setDaemon (true); taskExecutor.setThreadPriority (Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); return taskExecutor;
}

Comment: `otherwise the endpoint not response until job finish`: That's not correct. Here is an excerpt from the docs I linked: `The controller launches a Job using a JobLauncher that has been configured to launch asynchronously, which immediately returns a JobExecution. The Job will likely still be running, however, this nonblocking behaviour allows the controller to return immediately, which is required when handling an HttpRequest`. The launcher will return immediately.

Comment: Please edit the question and add code instead of adding code in comments. `I have tried with this and the behavior is the same`: Declaring a `JobLauncher` bean is not the way to provide a custom launcher, you need to provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` and override `getJobLauncher`. That's why your custom launcher is not taken into account. This is explained in the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig.

Comment: As you suggested, I have been able to dismiss the use of the `DeferredResult` class creating and configuring a custom task executor to launch concurrent task. Now it seems that both files are entire processing correctly but writer isn't inserting anything in database

Comment: That's another issue, please open a new question for the writing issue and I will help there. Please accept this answer as it answers your initial question .

Comment: Thanks in advanced. [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66867561/5668022)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66852564/5668022) from @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, I was able to resolve the issue. To help with the implementation, in case someone comes to this question, I share the code that, in my case, has worked to solve the problem:

- Controller

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job job;

@GetMapping(value = "/process", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void get(@RequestParam("id") Integer idCarga) throws JobExecutionException
{
    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("mainJob", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .addString("idCarga", String.valueOf(idCarga))
            .toJobParameters();

    jobLauncher.run(job, params);
}
```

- Batch config, job and steps

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer
{
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepSkipListener stepSkipListener;

    @Autowired
    private MainJobExecutionListener mainJobExecutionListener;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("batch-thread-");

        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception
    {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step mainStep(ReaderImpl reader, ProcessorImpl processor, WriterImpl writer)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<List<ExcelLoad>, Invoice>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ExceptionSkipPolicy())
                .listener(stepSkipListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job mainJob(Step mainStep)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
                                .listener(mainJobExecutionListener)
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .start(mainStep)
                                .build();
    }
}
```

If after applying this code, as it happened to me, you have also had problems inserting the records in the database, you can go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871877/5668022) where I also put the code that works for me.