# Spring Batch processes the records, but is not inserting them into the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch

### Issue

When I've started to use separate threads to run the same job several times at the same time, it's happening that the records that have to be inserted, when they've been processed, from the Writer aren't being inserted into the database. The batch runs correctly when I run two sets of data at the same time:

- Records processed dataSet1: 3606 (expected 3606).
- Records processed dataSet2: 1776 (expected 1776).

As can be seen in the following image, the number of records read and written by Spring Batch are as expected:
[image]

### Context

In this project I'm using MySQL as database and Hibernate.

### Some code

- Batch config, job and steps

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer
{
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepSkipListener stepSkipListener;

    @Autowired
    private MainJobExecutionListener mainJobExecutionListener;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("batch-thread-");

        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception
    {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step mainStep(ReaderImpl reader, ProcessorImpl processor, WriterImpl writer)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<List<ExcelLoad>, Invoice>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ExceptionSkipPolicy())
                .listener(stepSkipListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job mainJob(Step mainStep)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
                                .listener(mainJobExecutionListener)
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .start(mainStep)
                                .build();
    }
}
```

- Writer

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Invoice> list)
{
    invoiceRepository.saveAll(list);
}
```

- Repository

```
@Repository
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Integer>
{}
```

- Properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_dev?autoReconnect=true&useTimezone=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Before using the separate threads, the processed records were inserted into the database correctly. What could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Before using the separate threads, the processed records were inserted into the database correctly. What could be happening?

If you decide to use a multi-threaded step, you need to make sure your batch artefacts (reader, writer, etc) are thread-safe. From what you shared, the write method is not synchronized between threads and hence is not thread-safe. This is explained in the [Multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) section of the documentation.

You need to either synchronize it (by using the `synchronized` key word, or using a `Lock`, etc) or wrap your writer in a [SynchronizedItemStreamWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamWriter.html).

Comment: Implementing a @Bean PlatformTransactionManager with a ItemWriter worked for me, the question is if this has any risk that I'm not aware of

Comment: What I understood from your question is that: `When I've started to use separate threads [..] from the Writer aren't being inserted into the database` meaning things worked as expected with a single threaded step but not when you started using multi-threading. So for me the transaction manager was not the issue, but rather "loosing" records not being written which could be due to multi-threading (ie one thread is overriding another thread's writes). Hence my answer to make sure everything is thread-safe. If this is the case, there is no risk.

Answer (score 0):

To help with the implementation, in case someone comes to this question, I share the code that, in my case, has worked to solve the problem:

- Batch config, job and steps

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer
{
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepSkipListener stepSkipListener;

    @Autowired
    private MainJobExecutionListener mainJobExecutionListener;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager()
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("batch-thread-");

        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception
    {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step mainStep(ReaderImpl reader, ProcessorImpl processor, WriterImpl writer)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager)
                .<List<ExcelLoad>, Invoice>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new ExceptionSkipPolicy())
                .listener(stepSkipListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job mainJob(Step mainStep)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
                                .listener(mainJobExecutionListener)
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .start(mainStep)
                                .build();
    }
}
```

- Writer

```
@Component
public class WriterImpl implements ItemWriter<Invoice>
{
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Invoice> list)
    {
        invoiceRepository.saveAll(list);
    }
}
```